# Is there a way to pull data from specific sheets from multiple workbooks and add them to an existing workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on this issue for a while and could really use some help. Below, I've got code that enables me to pick out and choose specific workbooks and output them to a new workbook. I'd ideally like to be able to add data from specific sheets to the master workbook (all sheets will have the same name and form). Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I had previously:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineDataFiles()

Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
Dim MaxNumberFiles As Long, FileIdx As Long, _
    LastDataRow As Long, LastDataCol As Long, _
    HeaderRow As Long, LastOutRow As Long
Dim DataRng As Range, OutRng As Range

'initialize constants
MaxNumberFiles = 2001
HeaderRow = 1 'assume headers are always in row 1
LastOutRow = 1

'prompt user to select files
Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With TargetFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

'error trap - don't allow user to pick more than 2000 files
If TargetFiles.SelectedItems.count > MaxNumberFiles Then
    MsgBox ("Too many files selected, please pick more than " & MaxNumberFiles & ". Exiting sub...")
    Exit Sub
End If

'set up the output workbook
Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)

'loop through all files
For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.count

    'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
    Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    Set DataSheet = DataBook.ActiveSheet

    'identify row/column boundaries
    LastDataRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastDataCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'if this is the first go-round, include the header
    If FileIdx = 1 Then
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    'if this is NOT the first go-round, then skip the header
    Else
        Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
        Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastOutRow + 1 + LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    End If

    'copy the data to the outbook
    DataRng.Copy OutRng

    'close the data book without saving
    DataBook.Close False

    'update the last outbook row
    LastOutRow = OutSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Next FileIdx

'let the user know we're done!
MsgBox ("Combined " & TargetFiles.SelectedItems.count & " files!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Still reading through your code, but separate from whatever I post as help, you need to fix your Too Many Files error message, it says the opposite of what you want :P

Comment: My help is: you would assign your specific sheets to Datasheet. Also, right now it will only grab one sheet per file, you would need a `For Each` loop to go through all the sheets in each file.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I only need it to grab one sheet within a file, so I think assigning a specific sheet to Datasheet solves that issue. Another problem I am facing is putting it in an already existing workbook. Do you have any advice on doing so? If not, no worries. I really appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Set DataSheet = DataBook.ActiveSheet
```

To

```
Set DataSheet = DataBook.Sheets("SheetName")
```

Also, if you want an existing workbook replace

```
Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
```

With

```
Set OutBook = AvtiveWorkbook
```

Or Some other workbook that you want to work with.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Though one problem remains, how do I add it to an existing workbook instead of creating a new one? Again, thank you for taking the time to help.